# What are the Main difference between CTE's and TEMP tables?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression, temp-tables

Is there a benefit to using `CTE's` (`common table expressions`) instead of using `temp tables`.

I went through performance testing between both of them, but I cant find much difference between them.

What are some pros and cons of using `CTE'S`?

Comment: From the DBA site [What's the difference between a CTE and a Temp Table?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13112/3690)

Comment: I don't know much about the performance differences, but cte's allow for simple looping and recursion, temp tables are handy if a query output will be accessed multiple times and re-running would be a waste of time.

Comment: They are different things, and really it is horses for courses. Which one is best will depend on your exact scenario. Your question is no less ambiguous than `What are the benefits of using Views rather than tables?`

Comment: CTE's also perform slower because the results are not cached. So everytime you use the CTE it re-runs the query, plan and all

Comment: ^ That's an important point, especially if the CTE/TT is working with millions of rows of data.

Comment: Query plans can become outdated, in which case that would be a benefit of a CTE.

Answer (score 18):

Probably the biggest difference between a CTE and a temp table, is that the CTE has an execution scope of a **single** SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement.

Essentially you can't reuse the CTE, like you can with temp tables.

From the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary
>   result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is
>   similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and
>   lasts only for the duration of the query. Unlike a derived table, a
>   CTE can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in
>   the same query.
>
> A CTE can be used to:
>
> 1. Create a recursive query. For more information, see Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions.
> 2. Substitute for a view when the general use of a view is not required; that is, you do not have to store the definition in metadata.
> 3. Enable grouping by a column that is derived from a scalar subselect, or a function that is either not deterministic or has external access.
> 4. Reference the resulting table multiple times in the same statement.

Comment: The biggest difference to me is that one is an actual table and the other isn't. There is a big difference between `WITH CTE AS (SELECT * FROM MillionRowTable) SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE` and `INSERT INTO #T SELECT * FROM MillionRowTable; SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #T`

Comment: @MartinSmith your comment has more votes than the answer itself!!

Comment: It can go the other way too: `insert into #table` followed by `select .. where xyz not in #table` is fast, but rewriting as a CTE makes it super slow.

Answer (score 8):

**CTE :** CTE stands for Common Table expressions. It was introduced with SQL Server 2005. It is used to store the result of a complex sub-query on temporary bases. Its life is limited to the current query. It is defined by using WITH statement. It mainly used for recursive call.

**Example**

```
;with myCTE as 
(
    select ParentLevel, ParentID, ChildID 
    from MHA 
    where ChildID = 1 
    UNION ALL
    select MHA.ParentLevel, MHA.ParentID, MHA.ChildID 
    from MHA
    inner join myCTE on MHA.ParentID = myCTE.ChildID
    where MHA.ParentID <> 0
)
```

**(error)**

```
select top (5) * from myCTE
```

so in above example, I have create CTE name as myCTE , that can only be used in above query (I can not use myCTE out side of above query)

**TEMP:** It is also used to store the result of query on temporary bases.But Its life is limited to the current session. It is defined by using #. It does not support recursive.

**Example:**

```
select * into #tempTable from MHA
```

In above query I have created temp table, now I can use it temp table out side of this query but with in session. See below

**(no error)**

```
select top (5) * from #tempTable
```