# SELECT INTO vs WITH AS: Who is faster in the temp table approach?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a little experience with these two structures. Is there a performance improvement using one or another to use temp tables?

- I know that `SELECT INTO` creates a table that persists after the query and is removed after some time. There is some problems when using the same query after a few seconds (SQL Error [2714] [S0001]: There is already an object named #XXXXX in the database). So, you don't need create the table again if you are making a lot of queries using that temp table at different approaches. It's a table that can be used by different users while exists, included.
- `WITH AS` just create the temp table in the current query and is immediately erased after that.

I have no more information.

Comment: *"`WITH AS` just create the temp table in the current query and is immediately erased after that."* `WITH` doesn't create a temporary table; that would be `CREATE TABLE #TempTableName ({Columns List})`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing two concepts.

`SELECT INTO` creates a new table.  That could be a temporary table or a permanent table.  But the *table* is created.

`WITH` defines a *common table expression* (CTE) used within a single query.  This is not a "table".  It is simply a subquery and it may or may not be materialized as a temporary table (actually, SQL Server does not typically materialize CTEs).

You use `SELECT INTO` when you want a real table.  Some reasons for that are:

- Sharing data among multiple queries.
- Collecting correct statistics to help the query optimizer.
- Adding indexes to improve subsequent query performance.

You use a CTE when you want a named subquery in a query.  If you are choosing between the two, you probably want to start with a CTE.

Comment: Thanks for your help! If the CTE is not materialized, for each CTE call is the same query runned all these times? I'm just concerned about many executions of the query search instead put in a cache/temp table.

Comment: @HelioJunior . . . How many times the code runs depends on the optimizer.  SQL Server has a tendency to re-run the code every time it is referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Oh boy where do I start?

First, see:

[What are the Main difference between CTE's and TEMP tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492326/what-are-the-main-difference-between-ctes-and-temp-tables)

There are BIG differences between these two.

Temp and Global Temp tables

- Can be indexed
- Persist past the statement that created them
- saved in tempdb for the current session

CTE's

- Temporary result set
- Can be used for recursion
- scope is statement

Now lets talk about some more anecdotal stuff, or common thing youll see:

They say make table query with temp tables are optimized for bulk insert performance, though I think i recall reading that in SQL Server 2019 thats no longer the case, but I havent seen evidence to support that yet. That being said, it is a real convenient way to replicate the table structure on the fly, so it’s a technique you’ll see in lots of places.

Another common temp table technique is used to prefilter a result set instead of trying to join a large table on the left side of a join with another larger table on the right side. This causes a bunch of reads and often makes sense to take the slice you need from the first table into a temp tables to gain performance by circumventing that behavior. Again, this is very common and something you should get used to thinking about when working with JOINS and larger tables.

Using a series of CTE’s for JOINS – Ive seen this a lot and its always bad. You end up losing performance with all the hash tables and looping required to joins multiple CTE’s in the final select query. It always ends up with gross amounts of unnecessary reads.

For whats its worth, most of the time with CTE’s, unless youre using them for recursive logic or to build a quick/easy cartesian product (or some other kind of easy to build list), I almost always rewriting them in favor of other techniques. That’s not necessarily a personal flavor kind of thing either, I just think in normal contexts the ability to index temp tables and table variables to be valuable. And there’s generally less reads happening over all. The idea here is to make sure you analyze both approaches and pick the one that is best overall.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend